# Runtime error : why gave me a runtime error I can't understand on codeforces 'Runtime error on test 1'

Tags: python, runtime-error

why gave me a runtime error I can't understand on codeforces 'Runtime error on test 1'

```
num=int(input())
arrs=[]
for x in range(0,num):
    ele=int(input())
    if ele > 0:
        arrs.append(1)
    elif ele < 0:
        arrs.append(2)
    else :
        arrs.append(ele)
    
for x in list(arrs):
    print(x)
```

Comment: because of this code rrs.append(1)

Comment: Presumably codeforces runs a bunch of tests against the code you wrote, of which test 1 is failing. Without knowing what codeforces task you're doing (presumably it's one of those garbage code kata like sites) there's not much we can do. The code itself is fine given no other information.